# can't use function more than once

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For some reason i can't seem to be able use my "player" function more than once so it means i can't update it's positioning can anyone help and explain why?

heres my code:

```js
var gridHeight = 1000, gridWidth = 1000, canvasHeight = 250, canvasWidth = 250, p = 0;
var currentPositionX = 0;
var currentPositionY = 0;

function buildGrid() {
 $("body").append("<canvas></canvas").css({
  height: canvasHeight, 
  width: canvasWidth, 
  border: "2px solid #000"
 });

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    $("#canvas").css({height: canvasHeight, width: canvasWidth});

 for (var x = 0; x <= gridWidth; x += 40) {
        context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
        context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, gridHeight + p);
    }


    for (var x = 0; x <= gridHeight; x += 20) {
        context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
        context.lineTo(gridWidth + p,x + p);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();

    function player(x, y, w, h, c) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
        this.h = h || 20;
        this.w = w || 40;
        this.c = c || "#FF0000";
    }

    function draw() {
        player = new player();
        context.fillstyle = player.c;
        context.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.w,player.h);

        $("#right").on("click", function() {
            player.x += player.w;
            return player.x;
        })
    }

    setInterval(draw, 500)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 buildGrid();
})
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/game.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body style=" background: lightblue;">
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <div id="controls">
  <button class="control" id="up">Up</button>
  <button class="control" id="left">Left</button>
  <button class="control" id="down">Down</button>
  <button class="control" id="right">Right</button>
  <button class="control" id="newPlayer">new player</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help? My aim is make the buttons move the square around the grid. But also it have inheritable properties for further functionality late on.

Answer (score 0):

`player = new player();` you overwrite your function definition with the result of its execution in `draw()`.

If you just add `var` in front of this line, the player var will be restricted to the scope of `draw()`, which might be what you want.

Comment: I just tried it and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: I think executing `draw()` from `setInterval()` deprives it from its expected context. Let me check how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j2q2qn2e/

snippet of javascript

```
function player(x, y, w, h, c) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
        this.h = h || 20;
        this.w = w || 40;
        this.c = c || "#FF0000";
    }
player = new player();

...

function draw() {

    context.fillstyle = player.c;
    context.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.w,player.h);
}

setInterval(draw, 3)
```

Basically you where creating a new player per draw, but what I have done is moved your player "class" outside of your calling functions and created it outside so we can create one basic player. I also moved your

```
$("#right").on("click", function() {
    player.x += player.w;
   return player.x;
});
```

to inside the jQuery doc ready because it needs to assign the event here not inside of your draw function or you would be adding multiple event listeners. So you can now use your right button correctly.